# Char -> Bool problems in filter function

Tags: haskell

Right now I'm working on a program that removes everything but "a" in a text element just as a practice problem, here's my code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Char as C
import qualified Data.Text as T

removeNonAs :: T.Text -> T.Text
removeNonAs txt = T.filter ("a") txt
```

My problem is with the placeholder "a" in T.Filter. Every time I try to run the program it gives an error message saying (class) isn't Char -> Bool. I used to use `` elem` "a" `` which worked fine but then I added OverloadedStrings Which made it not work and give an "ambiguous type variable" error message. I am very confused with what made `` elem` "a" `` stop working, what the whole Char -> Bool thing is about, and what to do. If you could help me thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By checking the type signature of filter: `filter :: (Char -> Bool) -> T.Text -> T.Text` we know that filter accept one function and one Text, the function accepts  Char and returns Bool then we can define removeNonAs like this:

```haskell
import qualified Data.Char as C
import qualified Data.Text as T

removeNonAs :: String -> T.Text
removeNonAs = T.filter (=='a') . T.pack
-- usage:
removeNonAs "abcabcabc"
"aaa"
```

T.pack convert String to Text.

also you can define more general form of removeNonAs:

```haskell
removeNonAsGeneral :: Char -> String -> T.Text
removeNonAsGeneral a = T.filter (==a) . T.pack
-- usage:
removeNonAsGeneral 'a' "abcdabcdabcd"
"aaa"
```

Comment: Sry I didn't get what you said

Comment: I just meant now that I'm looking at it =='a' seems obvious. But still thanks bcs I definitely wouldn't have realized that w/o this answer. also for T.Filter (=='a') . T.pack you would need to change the type to String -> T.Text

Comment: For completeness: the reason that ```(`elem` "a")``` didn't work with `OverloadedStrings` on is that `elem` is polymorphic over containers, and `"a"` is polymorphic over string-like things. There could be many container, string-like things, and it doesn't know which to pick.

Comment: idk any of what you said but thanks for explaining it anyways lol